# Как организовать прокси с интерфейса на интерфейс?

Tags: linux, debian, proxy, iptables

ОС: Linux debian 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux

---

Три сетевых интерфейса:
1. **enp0s3** - статический IP
2. **ppp100** - динамический IP
2. **ppp200** - динамический IP

---

Возникла необходимость организовать http/https прокси: когда запросы приходят на enp0s3 порт 8080 пускать трафик через ppp100, а если запросы приходят на на enp0s3 порт 8081 пускать трафик через ppp200, т.е. в зависимости от порта пускать трафик через разные интерфейсы.
Можно ли такое организовать стандартными средствами iptables? Я пробовал по [вот этому примеру](https://serverfault.com/questions/438425/iptables-how-to-forward-packets-with-destination-port-80-from-eth0-to-eth1), однако ничего у меня не получилось. Был бы рад любой помощи или совету. Спасибо

Comment: Что должно происходить с ip адресами в пакетах ? Изначально в пакетах какой ip назначения, вот с тем 8081 портом, тот что стоит на enp0s3 или какой то адрес в интернете или еще где нибудь ? И что дальше с этим адресом должно произойти, он меняется на некий ip, находящийся за нужным ppp интерфейсом или адрес остается без изменений. И что должно произойти с ip отправителя пакета, что бы он гарантированно вернулся через нужный ppp возможно он должен и уйти с ip этого интерфейса

Comment: И вы уверены, что это именно http-прокси. потому что http-прокси принято называть соответствующие программы, которые реализуют соответствующий протокол и которые сами по себе и никакого отношения к iptables не имеют. Подсказка: вы используете http-прокси в том случае, если явно указали его в настройках браузера

Comment: на выходе должен быть IP адрес либо ppp100, либо ppp200, смотря на какой порт enp0s3 пришел пакет соответственно.  Название не важно, моей конечной задачей является, чтобы в зависимости от порта входа трафика на enp0s3 выбирался разный интерфейс для выхода в Сеть. Я не силен в этом, поэтому могу ошибаться в терминах

Comment: у пакета есть два адреса - отправителя и получателя. Если поменять получателя на ip интерфейса, то пакет далее никуда не уйдет. я спрашиваю про оба ip адреса, что с каким из них должно происходить. И кстати, что должно происходить с портом назначения, на том адресе куда он направляется, кто то ожидает пакеты на соответствующем порту ?

Comment: [Вот такая схема](https://imgur.com/a/u44Za) вот так я это вижу. http-прокси, т.к. предполагается это все для работы по протоколу http/https. Возможно это решается иным, относительно iptables, путем, однако как это сделать я не представляю

Comment: картинка не говорит ни о чем. самое главное понимать что происходит с ip адресами отправителя и получателя в пакетах и указана ли прокси явно в настройках браузера. или каким еще образом пакеты направляются клиентами именно на указанные порты 8081, а не на страндартные 80. клиенты в url явно задают этот адрес или это как раз через настройки прокси в браузере происходит

Comment: да, естественно в настройках прокси браузера явно будет указан IP адрес enp0s3 и порт(8080 или 8081). Тогда предполагается, что весь трафик браузера пойдет через enp0s3, который в свою очередь направит трафик по одному из других интерфейсов

Comment: тогда вам iptables вообще не поможет, потому что он может только поменять ip-адреса в пакетах и правила маршрутизации. А в случае указания адреса прокси в настройках браузера, браузер обращается к указанному порту через специальный протокол http-прокси, который не совпадает с обычным протоколом http и следовательно должна быть программа, которая выполнит действия переданные по этому протоколу и пошлет далее обращение от своего имени по другому протоколу. соответственно такую программу надо установить и настроить...

Comment: часто используют squid, но он сложен в освоении, можно поискать еще что нибудь другое. например я как то использовал 3proxy. Вообще таких серверов пара десятков разных наберется. правда какой из них умеет работать с двумя исходящими каналами еще надо посмотреть

Comment: я поднимал 3proxy и указывал слушать два разных порта + соответственно перенаправлять трафик по разным интерфейсам: однако одно перенаправление работало, а второе нет. Работал ppp200, а ppp100 не работал. Возможно потому что ppp200 поднимался после ppp100. Однако как это связано и причину я так и не понял. ppp100 и ppp200 это соединения через 3G модемы

Comment: так, уже хорошо. т.е. в нем можно указать ip с которого отправлять пакеты ? Если да, то что бы это заработало вам надо еще немного подкрутить маршрутизацию. вам потребуются два маршрута по умолчанию и правила маршрутизации. делается это все с помощью утилиты ip. с помощью ip route добавляет второй default в отдельную таблицу маршрутизации и потом `ip ru add prio 100 src ip-ppp0 lookup tab-num` где ip-ppp0 адрес с соотв. интерфейса и tab-num номер таблицы маршрутизации в которой лежит нужный default.

Comment: но вам надо будет еще сделать свои скрипты поднятия ppp-интерфейсов, которые будут эти правила автоматически создавать при поднятии интерфейсов, что бы в нужную таблицу маршрутизации записать нужный ip шлюза по умолчанию (default gateway) https://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/

Comment: не подскажите как прописать второй default для интерфейса с IP например 100.101.102.103?

Comment: ip самого интерфейса значения не имеет. надо знать ip-адрес шлюза. что бы для начала руками все попробовать, опускаете оба ppp интерфейса, поднимаете один из них, смотрите текущую таблицу `route -n` там будет поднятая автоматически с ppp интерфейсом запись default, что то вроде `0.0.0.0         10.0.1.250  ...` после чего делаете `ip ro add default tab 2 dev ppp0 via 10.0.1.250`. в таблицу 2 добавили default. после чего удаляете обычный default (`route del default`), поднимаете второй ppp интерфейс, делаете то же, только в команде `tab 3` (3 я таблица)

Comment: после этого делаете `ip ru add prio 10 from 100.101.102.103 lookup 2` (тут ip самого интерфейса) и такое же правило для Ip со второго интерфейса, только lookup 3

Comment: когда все руками поднятое заработает надо будет смотреть /etc/ppp там должны быть файлы/папки у которых в именах что то вроде ip-up. вот там пишутся скрипты на поднятие интерфейсов, у них на входе в параметрах есть и имя интерфейса и его ip и адрес шлюза. вот в них и пишутся те команды ip ro/ip ru, которые настраивают правила с текущими параметрами полученными от провайдера